# ReactNative Integration with Existing App not RCT_EXPORT_METHOD macro

Tags: ios, react-native

Integration with Existing App

There is not `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` macro in `RCTBridgeModule.h` file and `RCT_EXPORT` macro exited.

How can I update?

In my podfile:

```
pod 'React'
pod 'React/RCTText'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the version to 0.4.0

```
pod 'React', '0.4.0'
pod 'React/RCTText', '0.4.0'
```

Comment: Yes , you are right again...My pods has something wrong, and I update cocaopods after that everything is working.